# Vagrant denying connections using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, vagrant

I've gone through the other answers on stack overflow, searched google, and still cannot figure this issue out.

I am using the following Vagrant configuration file:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty32"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisioner.sh"
```

I don't see anything in the provisioner.sh file that seems relevant, but will post if someone thinks it is important.

I start the VM up using VirtualBox and Vagrant.  I initialize a php server using

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

However, I cannot get access to any of the php files I am attempting to open in Chrome.  I've tried localhost:8000 (can't be reached), localhost:8080 (403: Forbidden), and localhost:8080/index.php (404: File Not Found).  Is there something I'm not configuring properly in the vagrant network configuration?

Comment: `netstat -anp | grep 80`  what do you have listed? It sounds like you may have nginx or apache running on 8080, so you may just need to configure and use that instead.

Comment: `tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:80 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 18227/nginx` is the response I'm getting

Comment: Since you are running the php server inside vagrant, you cannot access port 8000 by using localhost:8000 from you host(chrome).  Add a private ip to vagrant box and use that IP to access the web server.

Comment: Port 8080 (localhost:8080) is forwarded to port 80 for nginx. You can modify the nginx configuration settings in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. If you want to set up another port to forward just for the built-in php server, you'll need to add it in your Vagrant configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues -

1. you serve your php files on localhost but your host will not be able to access them, to make your VM files accessible from your host, you can do

   ```
   php -S 0.0.0.0:8000
   ```
2. your host has no access to the port 8000 of the VM so if you're using this port in your VM you need to tell vagrant to forward this port on your host. In your Vagrantfile add

   ```
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 8000
   ```

This was you will be able to access your site from the VM on your host using `localhost:8000`

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: what is the error ? can you confirm its up and running from the guest ? can you run `curl localhost:8000` from your host ?